# Developer Commentary without Completing the Chamber

Tags: steam, portal

I've played (and finished) the original Portal on my Xbox 360. I really liked the game, and thought many times about having another go to listen to the developer commentary. However, I do not fancy another play-through using that wicked game-pad contraption.

Recently I picked up the PC version on steam. To my utter chagrin, it requires me to finish a chamber before being able to access the commentary. This would mean two entire play-throughs, which is a bit much even using keyboard and mouse.

Is there some way to convince the game that I've played it already and let me listen to the commentary unhindered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Finish the first level.
2. Return to the main menu.
3. Start over in developer commentary mode.

You should now be able to finish the entire game with developer commentary on. (You are however giving up on achievements.)

Comment: No achievements is OK. I'm trying it out right now.

Comment: IIRC, you can't save your game with commentary on, either.

Comment: It works like a charm. I just saved-and-loaded and that went ok too. You are my hero! :P

Comment: @Ben That's Portal 2.